# Keep form data inside input fields after form error checking

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a small form, Im doing some simple error checking with php and all looks to be well but I notice when users submit the form, after the error checking happens all data is removed from the fields.

Here is what I have

```
<?php if($show=="true"):?>
<input name="fname" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name']){echo $_POST['name';]})?>"><?php echo $errorname; ?>

<input name="email" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name']){echo $_POST['name';]})?>"><?php echo $erroremail; ?>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
<?php else: ?>
<h2>Your Message was sent</h2>

 <?php endif;?>
<?php
    if(empty($_POST['name'])){
         $show="true";
         $errorname="please enter your name";
     }
     elseif(empty($_POST['email'])){
        $show=true;
        $erroremail="please end your email";
     }else
        $show=false;
        //Send data as email;

    ?>
```

Comment: Do you use AJAX request in this case?

Comment: No I don't, I've never worked with AJAX. Would that be the way to go to accomplish this?

Comment: OT: don't use `"true"` and `"false"` strings, use the built-in boolean values `true` and `false`. That way you can just write `if ($show)`.

Comment: Where do you set the value of `$show`, other than in your if/else?

Comment: `echo $_POST['name';]` is invalid. The `;` must be outside the brackets: `echo $_POST['name'];`. Is that a copying error?

Comment: Why are you displaying the form before setting the variables `$show` and `$errorname`?

Comment: Nowhere else, the only purpose of it is to keep showing the form as long as there are blank fields/errors, and only change the value of $show when all fields are filled and submitted.

Comment: echo $_POST['name';] Yes that was a copy error, I have my code on another computer and just typed this up, sorry about that.

Comment: $errorname works but I should wrap it in a isset()? Is that considered good practice?

Comment: The form works, but when users press the submit button if one of the fields where left empty the form continues to show but all the text inside of the fields get erased.

Comment: Not what you asked, but don't just "echo" out user input. Always use htmlspecialchars or you will have some bad results if the input contains html characters

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if fields are empty (which is weird), you could just use the post values on the last submission. After that, just use `empty()`, if there are indeed, errors, put them inside an array (gather them) and print them after submission. Consider this example:

```
<?php
$errors = array();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fname = trim($_POST['fname']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);

    if(empty($fname)) {
        $errors['fname'] = 'please enter your name';
    }
    if(empty($email)) {
        $errors['email'] = 'please enter your email';
    }
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="index.php">
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['fname']) ? $_POST['fname'] : ''; ?>" /> <span style="color: red;"><?php echo isset($errors['fname']) ? $errors['fname'] : ''; ?></span><br/>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : ''; ?>" /> <span style="color: red;"><?php echo isset($errors['email']) ? $errors['email'] : ''; ?></span><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php if(isset($_POST['submit']) && empty($errors)): ?>
    <h2>Your Message was sent.</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```